# C++ if condition not working

Tags: c++

I have an array of objects

```
Passenger travellers[] = {
    Passenger(nullptr, "Toronto", 2018, 4, 20),
    Passenger("", "Toronto", 2018, 4, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", nullptr, 2018, 4, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", "", 2018, 4, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2018, 4, 20), // valid
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2028, 4, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2014, 4, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2020, 12, 31), // valid
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2018, 40, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2018, 0, 20),
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2017, 1, 1), // valid
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2018, 4, 0),
    Passenger("John Smith", "Toronto", 2018, 4, 32),
    Passenger(nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0, 0),
    Passenger()
};
```

and my constructors are:

default constructor

```
Passenger::Passenger() {
    p_name[0] = '\0';
    p_dest[0] = '\0';

    // destination date
    d_yy = 0;
    d_mm = 0;
    d_dd = 0;
}
```

And my other constructor with parameters are:

```
Passenger::Passenger(const char *name, const char *destination, int year, int month, int days) {

    if (name != nullptr && destination != nullptr && name[0] != '\0' && destination[0] != '\0') {
        if (year >= 2017 && year <= 2020 && month >= 1 && month <= 12 && days >= 1 && days <= 31) {
            strncpy(p_name, name, 32);
            strncpy(p_dest, destination, 32);
            d_yy = year;
            d_mm = month;
            d_dd = days;
        }
        else 
            Passenger();
    }
    else
        Passenger();
}
```

Problem is the rest of the objects should return "not valid" but the very first object is returning "valid" instead even though it has a **nullptr**  value. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the full definition of `Passenger` (in particular, the types of each of the data members)

Comment: Insufficient information.  You have not specified what the types of the members of `Passenger` are.     The `Passenger()` statements in the second constructor don't "reset" the object - they create a temporary that immediately ceases to exist.   Without a definition of the `Passenger` class, nobody can help you beyond that.

Answer (score 3):

Following:

```
else {
    Passenger();
}
```

just create a temporary (immediately destroyed), you might want to throw instead, or for default initialization it would be:

```
Passenger::Passenger(const char *name,
                     const char *destination,
                     int year,
                     int month,
                     int days) : Passenger() // Delegating constructor
{
    if (name != nullptr
       && destination != nullptr
       && name[0] != '\0'
       && destination[0] != '\0') {
        if (year >= 2017 && year <= 2020
           && month >= 1 && month <= 12
           && days >= 1 && days <= 31) {
            strncpy(p_name, name, 32);
            strncpy(p_dest, destination, 32);
            d_yy = year;
            d_mm = month;
            d_dd = days;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call the default `Passenger()` constructor from **inside of the BODY** of the other `Passenger(...)` constructor like you are trying to do.

You are actually constructing temporary `Passenger` objects that go out of scope right away:

```
Passenger::Passenger(const char *name, const char *destination, int year, int month, int days)
{
    if (name != nullptr && destination != nullptr && name[0] != '\0' && destination[0] != '\0')
    {
        if (year >= 2017 && year <= 2020 && month >= 1 && month <= 12 && days >= 1 && days <= 31)
        {
            strncpy(p_name, name, 32);
            strncpy(p_dest, destination, 32);
            d_yy = year;
            d_mm = month;
            d_dd = days;
        }
        else {
            Passenger(); // <-- TEMP OBJECT!!
        }
    }
    else {
        Passenger(); // <-- TEMP OBJECT!!
    }
}
```

You are NOT default constructing the current object that is being constructed with input values, like you are expecting.

The ONLY place that you can call another constructor of the same class is in the member initialization list (this is a C++11 feature known as **Delegating Constructors**), eg:

```
Passenger::Passenger(const char *name, const char *destination, int year, int month, int days)
    : Passenger() // <-- setup default values here...
{
    // overwrite default values as needed...
    if ((name) && (destination) &&
        (name[0] != '\0') && (destination[0] != '\0') &&
        (year >= 2017) && year <= 2020) &&
        (month >= 1) && (month <= 12) &&
        (days >= 1) && (days <= 31))
    {
        strncpy(p_name, name, 32);
        strncpy(p_dest, destination, 32);
        d_yy = year;
        d_mm = month;
        d_dd = days;
    }
}
```